# I want to replicate an experiment in cell biology, and I have a question about centrifuge RPM vs. x g

Tags: centrifugation

https://med.stanford.edu/news/all-news/2019/10/cytoplasm-of-scrambled-frog-eggs-organizes-into-cell-like-struct.html  This is the experiment which I want to replicate.  In the article describing the experiment, they said that they used a centrifuge capable of 12000 x g for 15 minutes.  I was wondering if I could possibly use a centrifuge with lower x g for a longer time interval and get the same result?  Like...possibly 6900 x g?

Comment: The new article you linked doesn't actually describe the methods used in that experiment, which are important here. While centrifugation time can in some cases make up for a lower speed it doesn't always work: some(/smaller) particles will not not sediment at all at lower speeds, independent on how long you run  the centrifuge.

Comment: @Nicolai The methods are in the supplemental data. They use microcentrifuges for their centrifugation step, which should be standard lab equiment. jeffrey Do you have a small centrifuge for 1,5ml tubes available in your lab?

Comment: Yes, I do have a small centrifuge capable of 10000 RPM.  It produces 6900 x g.

Comment: It's the question if they used 12.000 rpm because it is needed to seperate the mixture or because they simply put it on max. speed. I wouldn't be surprised if the answer is the later. You can of course have a try and see, if you can get a good separation with your centrifuge.